# protocol error: mtime.sec not present when tried to transfer folder/file from remote server to local

Tags: ubuntu, unix, cloud, remote-server

I am using Ubuntu 20 on alicloud and I have an issue when trying to copy from sftp remote server to local using cl:

```sh
scp -r -P 22 sftpibas@localhost:/sftpibas dev
```

but it raised

```
protocol error: mtime.sec not present
```

If you want to look into my config here I attach my sshd_config:

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

PermitRootLogin yes

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

UsePAM yes

PrintMotd no

AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

Match group sftp
ChrootDirectory /home
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Is my method to copy the files from the remote server to local wrong? Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried to run scp -v. That gave me a bit more information:

```
Sink: This service allows sftp connections only.
protocol error: mtime.sec not present
```

And I try it with sftp it works.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue on one of my Redat 8 box's after I rebuilt the server

I ran scp -v and noticed that 'Sink:' was showing a status message that I had added (echo "...") to my .bashrc file

Once I removed the echo statement scp ran without an issue

Answer (score 1):

The sshd_config is forcing connections to sftp, and the (oblique) error is the result.

Remove this line then reload/restart sshd:

```
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error and after adding `-v` to the scp command I learned that the error was caused by too many logins by my account to the remote box.

```
scp -v example.com:/tmp/example .
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -f /tmp/example
Sink: Too many logins for 'user1'
protocol error: mtime.sec not present
```